# Laravel Mail Connection could not be established Mailhog

Tags: php, laravel

I've installed Laravel Breeze and the 'forgot password' functionallity does not work.
Login and registrer both work well, so I guess there is something wrong at sending the recovery email.

This is the displayed error:

```
"Connection could not be established with host "mailhog:1025": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution"
```

at Symfony \ Component \ Mailer \ Exception \ TransportException.

and here is an screenshot:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj7no.png)

This is part of my .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

The environment is:

- Ubuntu 21.10
- Laravel 9.7.0
- PHP 8.0.8

Tested via `php artisan serve`

This is a new Laravel project in which I only installed Laravel Breeze for login handling. Laravel Sail is installed.

Comment: try replace `mailhog ` to `localhost ` in the .env file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add this `127.0.0.1 mailhog` in your **hosts** file
and change this `MAIL_HOST=0.0.0.0` in .env file or use `MAIL_HOST=localhost`

also you can check if your mailhog is enabled

```
sudo service mailhog status
```

To enable:

```
sudo systemctl enable mailhog
```

To start:

```
sudo systemctl start mailhog
```